# IBM Worklight 6.0 - FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure

Tags: json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm studying the worklight (6.0) tutorial (Insurance App) and in the chapter "Lab6_Integrate_With_Worklight_Apdaters_Part1_HTTPAdapter.pdf" I am instructed on how to create a procedure and invoke it. getting the json file strait from the worklight console URL works fine but when I build the procedure according to the tutorial I cant get the json file (in the "Invoke worklight procedure"), and receive an error:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project InsuranceProj]CustomerDataAdapter/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project InsuranceProj]{    "arr": [
      {
         "method": "get",
         "path": "\/apps\/services\/www\/Insurance\/mobilewebapp\/default\/json\/Customer.json",
         "returnedContentType": "json"
      }    ] } Failed to parse JSON string <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <meta content="en-us" name="DC.Language" />......    "
```

I am doing the exact steps in the tutorial and can't find out what's wrong....
I cant find any solution for this problem, Hope to get some answers here

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="CustomerDataAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>CustomerDataAdapter</displayName>
    <description>CustomerDataAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>localhost</domain>
            <port>10080</port>  
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getCustomerData">
        <displayName>GetCustomerData</displayName>
    </procedure>


</wl:adapter>
```

implementation file:

```
 function getCustomerData() {
    WL.Logger.debug("CustomerDataAdapter.getCustomerData procedure invoked");
    var input = {
            //headers : 'Content-Type: application/json',
            method : 'get',
            returnedContentType : 'json',
            path : "/apps/services/www/Insurance/mobilewebapp/default/json/Customer.json"
        };

        return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the lab you are following?  The only references that I can find to it are on a Chinese education site.  Your adapter call is retuning HTML … looks like something is pointed in the wrong direction.  Could you show your adapter XML and implementation?

Comment: Agreed; a reference to the project you are using is required.

Comment: I cannot find that tutorial, seems IBM took it down from their site... anyhow, i dag in and found out that the error rises from the response from the server is a 401 Unauthorized so maybe there is a security problem? 
the returned HTML file that i get in the response is actually the 401 page i get from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter is trying to get the JSON from

```
http://localhost:10080/apps/services/www/Insurance/mobilewebapp/default/json/Customer.json
```

Which is a reference back into your project (a fairly strange thing to do, but I guess in a lab …)

In any case, your path is missing an element.  It should be:

```
path : "/Insurance/apps/services/www/Insurance/mobilewebapp/default/json/Customer.json"
```

Comment: just to be clear … the first element of the path should be the project name.   I had assumed that the project name and the App name were both Insurance, but if the project name is something else … use whatever it is.

Comment: Yes! thank you very much!
apparently this is one of the changes they made from WorkLight 5.xx to WorkLight 6.xx - adding the name of the Project itself to the path url.
Just got the same answer you gave me from our IBM contuct guy,
the only difference is that the URL is without the "/" before the Project name, which will look like that:
' "Insurance[name of Project]/apps/services/www/Insurance[name of App]/mobilewebapp/default/json/Customer.json" '

and again thanks a lot from all of you guys, you are big helpers!

Answer (score 1):

When the adapter procedure makes its HTTP request to the back-end it is expecting a JSON encoded data string to be returned.  From the snippet of data that you show, it appears that what is actually returned is an HTML fragment.  What I would suggest is examining the data returned from the back-end service provider very carefully to determine if you are getting the data that you expected to see.